# Apache spark output messages are prepended by [error]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

This word count works as expected :

```
System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "H:\\winutils");

val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("GroupBy Test").setMaster("local[1]")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val text_file = sc.textFile("h:\\data\\small.txt")

  val counts = text_file.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
      .map(word => (word, 1))
      .reduceByKey(_ + _)

  counts.foreach(println);
}
```

All output messages are prepended by [error]
example :

```
[error] 16/03/17 12:13:58 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on por
[error] 16/03/17 12:13:58 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 55715
[error] 16/03/17 12:13:58 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
[error] 16/03/17 12:13:58 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager localhost:55715 with 1140.4 MB RAM, BlockManage
[error] 16/03/17 12:13:58 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
```

I can prevent these error messaged being displayed using :

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level

Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)
```

But this does not fix the issue.

[error] should not be displayed as these are not error messages but are info :

```
[error] 16/03/17 12:13:58 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on por
[error] 16/03/17 12:13:58 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 55715
[error] 16/03/17 12:13:58 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
[error] 16/03/17 12:13:58 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager localhost:55715 with 1140.4 MB RAM, BlockManage
[error] 16/03/17 12:13:58 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
```

Update :

Why are [error] messages being displayed as they are not errors ?

Comment: setting Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF) will only make the error messages not displayed. it will not deal with the problem but 'kill the messanger'
did you try setLevel(Level.Warn) ??

Comment: @Zahiro Mor it does not deal with the problem as I have said "But this does not fix the issue." my question is why are [error] messages being displayed as they are not errors ?

Comment: are you running this from an IDE or via spark submit?

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk running via sbt : "run"

Answer (score 4):

Those are not Spark labels but sbt ones. In the default `log4j` config file of Spark you can find:

`log4j.appender.console.target=System.err`

So by default it will print to `stderr` in the console.

You probably are setting `fork` to `true` in your `run` config somewhere. When doing so everything that is printed to `stderr` in sbt is prepended with `[error]`.

You should be able to control it with the [OutputStrategy](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Forking.html).